# How to find another related row without a loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
product_no    part_no    level  
1              1_1         1    
1              1_2         1    
1              1_3         2     
1              1_4         1     
1              1_5         1  
1              1_6         2 
1              1_7         2 
1              1_8         3 
1              1_9         3 
1              1_10        2 
2              2_1         1 
2              2_2         1 
2              2_3         2  
2              2_4         1
```

In this dataframe, I am trying to write a function to recall the row that has one lower leveled part than the selected row. For example, for the part `1_3`, the lower leveled part is `1_2`. For `1_7` , it is `1_5`, for `1_9`, it is `1_7` and so an so forth. I am already making this operation via a for loop but I was wondering that would there be a more efficient method to what I do here.

Comment: Your logic seems to be `lower_leveled_part = last part_no where level == current level - 1`. Following that logic, does the lower level part for `1_10` equal `1_5`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a loopless way to do it but it's gonna make your head spin. And by the way, I assume you want to separate it by `product_no`, hence the group by:

```
def last_part_no(group):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(group['level'])

    idx = dummies.index.to_series()
    last_index = dummies.apply(lambda col: idx.where(col != 0, np.nan).fillna(method='ffill'))
    last_index[0] = np.nan

    idx = last_index.lookup(last_index.index, group['level'] - 1)
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'last_prod_no': group.reindex(idx)['part_no'].values
    }, index=group.index)

df['last_part_no'] = df.groupby('product_no').apply(last_part_no)
```

Result:

```
    product_no part_no  level last_part_no
0            1     1_1      1          NaN
1            1     1_2      1          NaN
2            1     1_3      2          1_2
3            1     1_4      1          NaN
4            1     1_5      1          NaN
5            1     1_6      2          1_5
6            1     1_7      2          1_5
7            1     1_8      3          1_7
8            1     1_9      3          1_7
9            1    1_10      2          1_5
10           2     2_1      1          NaN
11           2     2_2      1          NaN
12           2     2_3      2          2_2
13           2     2_4      1          NaN
```

---

#### Here's how it works:

`groupby` divide the dataframes by `product_no` and send each subframe into the `last_part_no` function:

```
    product_no part_no  level
0            1     1_1      1
...
-----------------------------
10           2     2_1      1
...
```

The real work happens inside the `last_part_no` function. Let's assume that the function is processing the first subframe, which is equivalent to calling:

```
subframe = df[df['product_no'] == 1]
last_part_no(subframe)
```

For your reference, here's the values of `subframe`:

```
   product_no part_no  level
0           1     1_1      1
1           1     1_2      1
2           1     1_3      2
3           1     1_4      1
4           1     1_5      1
5           1     1_6      2
6           1     1_7      2
7           1     1_8      3
8           1     1_9      3
9           1    1_10      2
```

`dummies` is the one-hot encoded form of the `level` column:

```
   1  2  3
0  1  0  0      --> this row is level 1 since the column 1 is "hot"
1  1  0  0      
2  0  1  0      --> this row is level 2 since the column 2 is "hot"
3  1  0  0
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  0
6  0  1  0
7  0  0  1      --> this row is level 3 since the column 3 is "hot"
8  0  0  1
9  0  1  0
```

Next, we take `dummies.index` and change it based on the "hotness" of each column: if the row is "hot", keep the index's value, otherwise, replace with `np.nan`. We then forward-fill those `nan`:

```
index  1       np.where(...)      fillna(...)
0      1       0                  0             --> as of index 0, last row with level 1 is row 0
1      1       1                  1
2      0       np.nan             1
3      1       3                  3
4      1  ==>  4             ==>  4
5      0       np.nan             4
6      0       np.nan             4
7      0       np.nan             4             --> as of index 7, last row with level 1 is row 4
8      0       np.nan             4
9      0       np.nan             4
```

Repeat it for all 3 columns and your `last_index` frame looks like this (column 0 was created for convenience, it's all `nan`):

```
     0    1    2    3  
0  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  
1  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN  
3  NaN  3.0  2.0  NaN  
4  NaN  4.0  2.0  NaN  
5  NaN  4.0  5.0  NaN  
6  NaN  4.0  6.0  NaN  
7  NaN  4.0  6.0  7.0  --> as of index 7, last row with level 1 is 4, with level 2 is 6, with level 3 is 7
8  NaN  4.0  6.0  8.0  
9  NaN  4.0  9.0  8.0  --> as of index 9, last row with level 1 is 4, with level 2 is 9, with level 3 is 8
```

Now, let's get back to our `level` column (i.e. `subframe['level']`). To find the `last_part_no`, go to `level - 1`:

```
    level  level-1
0       1        0
1       1        0
2       2        1
3       1        0
4       1        0
5       2        1
6       2        1
7       3        2
8       3        2
9       2        1
```

Combine it with the `last_index` frame and you can find the **index** of the row containing the `last_part_no` for each row. This is the purpose of the `lookup` call:

```
The row index of last_part_no ...                 idx
                                                  ---
   for row 0 is in row 0, col 0 of last_index --> nan
           1       row 1, col 0               --> nan
           2       row 2, col 1               --> 1
           3       row 3, col 0               --> nan
           4       row 4, col 0               --> nan
           5       row 5, col 1               --> 4
           6       row 6, col 1               --> 4
           7       row 7, col 2               --> 6
           8       row 8, col 2               --> 6
           9       row 9, col 1               --> 4
```

The final step is to get the `part_no` column in the order prescribed in `idx` to become `last_part_no`:

```
   product_no part_no  level  last_part_no
0           1     1_1      1           nan
1           1     1_2      1           nan
2           1     1_3      2           1_2
3           1     1_4      1           nan
4           1     1_5      1           nan
5           1     1_6      2           1_5
6           1     1_7      2           1_5
7           1     1_8      3           1_7
8           1     1_9      3           1_7
9           1    1_10      2           1_5
```

Comment: First of all, wow! I am extremely impressed with this method and it surely made my head spin as you said at the start of the answer. Thank you for all the time you spent for the explanation, without it I may have been a little confused but now, everything is just clear. Just a little head's up to prevent any misunderstanding for someone else: i think at the last subframe, last_part_no of row 2 should be 1_2.

Comment: Also, if you dont mind me asking and if I'm not being too much, can a similar approach be applied for this another similar problem I'm currently having with the same type of dataframe? [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891442/how-to-drop-rows-according-to-data-relationship-between-rows)

Comment: An transcription error on my part. Thanks for the correction